# Magento get XML rewrited url

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have url rewrite, created with config.xml like this:

```
<saunas_cities>
    <from><![CDATA[#^/saunas/cities(.*)#]]></from>
    <to><![CDATA[/companies/catalog/cities/$1/]]></to>
    <complete>0</complete>
</saunas_cities>
```

Is there a way, to get rewrited url `(www.site.com/saunas/sities.html)` in template file?

Comment: Styopchik, please provide more details.... From which url to which url you want to rewrite

Comment: you have rewrited your url from `saunas/cities(.*)` to `companies/catalog/cities/$1`. but you are asking for **`get rewrited url (www.site.com/saunas/cities.html)`**. do you need `www.site.com/saunas/cities.html` or `www.site.com/companies/catalog/cities/html`?

Comment: i need something like this: `echo Mage::getUrl('companies/catalog/cities')` that will return `www.site.com/saunas/cities.html`

Answer (score -1):

I have  rewrite checkout cartcontroller

```
<global>
            <rewrite>
                <customcart>
                    <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
                    <to>/customcart/index/</to>
                </customcart>
            </rewrite>
    </global>
```

Comment: he is not actually asking for that